# How to merge two arrays (song&title) into one multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
Array 
( 
 [0] => Black 
 [1] => Five Hours 
 [2] => Bvulgari 
 [3] => Imaginary 
)

Array 
( 
 [0] => Pearl Jam
 [1] => Deorro
 [2] => Daddy's Groove
 [3] => Brennan Heart
)
```

I want to be able to achieve the following:
I want to have the song title and the Artist into one 'dimension' of the array,
This is how I want it to be:

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array 
            (
              [0] => Black
              [1] => Pearl Jam
            )
     [1] => Array
            (
              [0] => Five Hours
              [1] => Deorro
            )
     [2] => Array
            (
              [0] => Bvulgari
              [1] => Daddy's Groove

            )
     [3] => Array
            (
              [0] => Imaginary
              [1] => Brennan Heart
            )

)
```

The two arrays that are the input can change depending on the requestor's input.

Comment: "The arrays can change depending on the requestor's input." -- what does this mean? The contents of the two arrays? The number of arrays? Whether both/all arrays have the same length? Or, something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple `foreach` loop:

```
$songs_artists = array();
foreach ($songs as $key => $title) {
    $songs_artists[] = array($title, $artists[$key]);
}
```

Output is as you desire. [Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/H2KEV)

Comment: is there a way to convert an array without quotes to an array with quotes, because your code has an input array with quotes?

Comment: @BastiaanBuitelaar your arrays have quotes in them. They just don't show up when you output the array using `print_r`. Try using `var_export` on your array and you will see them show up e.g. https://3v4l.org/Fnn3P

Comment: Nick, your code outputs 'Array' without anything else, what can be the problem?

Comment: @BastiaanBuitelaar  array length will be identical in all cases or will varry?

Comment: @BastiaanBuitelaar  that simply means you are not using code correctly

Comment: @BastiaanBuitelaar the code works fine - see my demo. You need to change the names of the variables in my code to match yours.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and use both array's:

```
$result = array_map(function ($s, $a) {
    return [$s, $a];
}, $songs, $artists);

print_r($result);
```

See a [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/JqZmY)

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Black
            [1] => Pearl Jam
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Five Hours
            [1] => Deorro
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bvulgari
            [1] => Daddy's Groove
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Imaginary
            [1] => Brennan Heart
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do is [Array_Combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
$songs_artists = array_combine($songs,$artists);


Array (
[Black] => Pearl Jam 
[Five Hours] => Deorro 
[Bvulgari] => Daddy's Groove 
[Imaginary] => Brennan Heart
)
```

Comment: No it's not. check OP's desired output

Comment: @AlivetoDie I didn't mean the expected output, but if OP came to know the option of array_combine then he could change the work flow depend on key and value